# How to alter allowed headers in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, auth0

I'm currently using Auth0 (and an Angular 2 GUI), which sends a header of the type `"x-xsrf-token"` in the request to a Spring Boot API.

I get the error:

> "XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3001/ping. Request header
>   field x-xsrf-token is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in
>   preflight response."

This is fair enough as the list of Access-Control-Response-Headers in Response Headers does not include `x-xsrf-token` (when debugging the request in the network tab in Chrome).

I have tried a number of solutions, the closest I think I have come is to override the configure method in `AppConfig`, and add in my own `CorsFilter`, like below:

```
(Imports removed for brevity)

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class AppConfig extends Auth0SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public Auth0Client auth0Client() {
        return new Auth0Client(clientId, issuer);
    }

    @Bean
    public Filter corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new     UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("Content-Type");
        config.addAllowedHeader("x-xsrf-token");
        config.addAllowedHeader("Authorization");
        config.addAllowedHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers");
        config.addAllowedHeader("Origin");
        config.addAllowedHeader("Accept");
        config.addAllowedHeader("X-Requested-With");
        config.addAllowedHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method");
        config.addAllowedHeader("Access-Control-Request-Headers");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);

        return new CorsFilter(source);
    }

    @Override
    protected void authorizeRequests(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/ping").permitAll().antMatchers("/").permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated();
    }

    String getAuthorityStrategy() {
        return super.authorityStrategy;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.addFilterAfter(auth0AuthenticationFilter(auth0AuthenticationEntryPoint()),
            SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(simpleCORSFilter(), Auth0AuthenticationFilter.class);
        authorizeRequests(http);http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.cors();
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately I have had no success with this, and still see the `x-xsrf-token` missing in the response header of my get request.

My base project is this: 
https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-spring-security-api-sample/tree/master/01-Authentication/src/main

Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: Just found out this option when configuration CORS : ``exposedHeaders`` , you can add headers you want to expose and the other applications can read them without proble.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately I solved this myself.  I removed this dependency here in the pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>auth0-spring-security-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

because it is an open source project on github, here https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spring-security-api.  I added the source code to my project in its own package, and added its dependencies to my pom.xml file.  Then I changed the doFilter method in the Auth0CORSFilter to include my x-xsrf-token:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, x-xsrf-token, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, " +
            "Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

Unfortunately, I now won't be able to switch versions as easily if I need to, I also have a slightly more cluttered codebase, however as I am new to Spring this was far easier than spending hours trying to override the Auth0CORSFilter Bean, if that was ever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Believe this is already under discussion on the issue you posted [here](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-spring-security-api-sample/issues/8) but thought it worth replying on SOF since you have raised the question here too.

What you can do, is modify your [AppConfig](https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-spring-security-api-sample/blob/master/01-Authentication/src/main/java/com/auth0/example/AppConfig.java) to override the CORS Filter setting from the [default library config](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spring-security-api/blob/master/src/main/java/com/auth0/spring/security/api/Auth0SecurityConfig.java#L77) with your own updated [CORS Filter implementation](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spring-security-api/blob/master/src/main/java/com/auth0/spring/security/api/Auth0CORSFilter.java)

I think in your case, this might be just appending **x-xsrf-token** to this line:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, " +
                "Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers");
```

However, as i have stated in the github issue (linked above), if you send me your HAR file I can verify this is definitely the case and provides a working solution for you.

Comment: All of your links are broken :-/

Comment: Not surprising since the answer was 2 years ago :)

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
@Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new     UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");

        config.addAllowedHeader("*");       
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");        
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);



        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;


    }
```

https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

Comment: I'm afraid I didn't have any luck with this.  There were no errors when I started up the server, but when I started running GET requests I kept getting the same "x-xsrf-token" complaints.  Thanks anyway

Comment: I tried this configuration and like @JackWooding I found it didn't work.  I then tried explicitly listing headers I was using in the `addAllowedHeader` section, and that made it work, despite the documentation stating that "*" was accepted as a wildcard.  I think there's some kind of bug lurking somewhere in the handling of these headers, but I'm not quite sure where.